# Unprojeting a line on the screen

Tags: 3d, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a line connecting two points of my model. I see a projection of this line on my screen and a want to map a point of that projection to the corresponding point in my model PoV.

Let `A = (x_a, y_a, z_a, 1.)` and `B=(x_b, y_b, z_b, 1.)` be the coordinates of two points of my line in the model PoV.

Let `M,V` and  `P` be the model, view and projection matrices.

Let `A_s = NDC_to_screen(P*V*M*A)` and `B_s = NDC_to_screen(P*V*M*B)` be the coordinates of `A` and `B` projections on my screen (assume that those two points are distinct).

Let `vec_AB_s = B_s - A-s` be the vector from `A_s`to `B_s` and let `C_s = A_s + lambda_s * vec_AB_s` be a point that lie on the line's projection on my screen.

How can I get the 3D coordinates of `C` so that `C_s = NDC_to_screen(P*V*M*C)` ? Something that would be usefull for me would be to have it in the form `C = A + lambda * vec_AB`

Answer (score 0):

> Let `vec_AB_s = B_s - A-s` be the vector from `A_s`to `B_s` and let `C_s = A_s + lambda_s * vec_AB_s` be a point that lie on the line's projection on my screen.

Since the line is being projected onto the screen, then lambda will not change as a ratio between points (assuming your lambda is 0 to 1.0).Simply use the lambda and apply to A and B.
`C = A + lambda * vec_AB` like you stated in your post.

Comment: Note that if you're using perspective projection, the movement of the point along the line on the screen and the movement of the corresponding point along the line in 3D space are not always linearly related. If the line recedes away from the camera, then evenly spaced points on the 3D line will be closer together on the screen at the far end of the line than they are at the near end. So you would need to transform lambda in this case.